# getting a value of selected radiobutton in LoadViewState

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

can i get a value of a selected radio button in LoadViewState event of the the WebControl and how? All the components are generated in codebehind, so i have those controls:

```
RadioButtonList rbl;
ListItem liOne;
ListItem liTwo;
```

at the moment i am stuck at that the overriden LoadViewState is not being invoked

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object o)
{
  action = rbl.SelectedValue;
  action2 = rbl.SelectedItem.Value;
  base.LoadViewState(o);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you wait until LoadPostData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to override the SaveViewState method. Radio buttons AFAIK have problems saving their selected state.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153240/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110205-1.aspx[link text](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153240/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110205-1.aspx)